# Редактировать дату запроса requests python

Tags: python, requests

можно ли в запросе изменить date в response headers?

```
Response Headers    
Date: Tue, 30 Jun 2020 10:35:53 GMT
```

Comment: response задаётся сервером, вот к серверу и обращайтесь с этой просьбой

Comment: В response headers находятся заголовки ответа, соответственно - там дата ответа, а не дата запроса. Поменять после получения ответа ее можно, но не понятно что это вам даст.

Comment: @insolor как ее можно поменять?

Comment: `response.headers['Date'] = 'какая-то другая дата'`

Answer (score 0):

С самой датой вы ничего не сделаете - это ответ от сервера, он ее сам установил. Вы можете просто заменить ее у себя, хотя не понимаю для чего:

```
response.headers['Date'] = 'другая дата'
```